# Skip a Step from beforeStep of StepExecutionListener in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have implemented a batch job where there is a sequence of multiple steps. I have also implemented a **CustomStepListener**.
For my business logic I have to check a Database entry in **beforeStep** of **StepExecutionListener**. If the database entry exists, that means the step is executed before, so I want to skip that step and go to the next one.

But I don't have any idea, how I can skip current step from **beforeStep**.

Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Comment: I think whether to execute the step or not, should be part of ``decider`` and not before step. please check this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#programmaticFlowDecisions

Comment: +1 to what pratap said. `beforeStep` is too late in the flow to skip the step. A decider is better suited for such decisions. I added an answer with an example and some more details.

Answer (score 1):

A `JobExecutionDecider` is better suited to decide if a step should be executed or not. In your case, you can perform the database check in the decider and make it return a status to be used for the flow definition. Here is an example:

```
public class MyDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        String status;
        if (dbEntryExists()) {
            status = "ENTRY_EXIST";
        }
        else {
            status = "ENTRY_NOT_EXIST";
        }
        return new FlowExecutionStatus(status);
    }
}
```

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
            .start(step1())
            .next(decider()).on("ENTRY_EXIST").to(step2())
            .from(decider()).on("ENTRY_NOT_EXIST").to(step3())
            .end()
            .build();
}
```

Please refer to the [Programmatic Flow Decisions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#programmaticFlowDecisions) section in the documentation for more details.